# Ban slash command discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make slash ban command, and I don't really know how to make multiple options. This is my code:

```
@slash.slash(name="ban", description="Zbanuj osobę", guild_ids=guild_ids, options=[
                create_option(
                  name="osoba",
                  description="Osoba do zbanowania",
                  option_type=6,
                  required=True
                )
                create_option(
                  name="powód",
                  description="Powód bana",
                  option_type=3,
                  required=True
                )
             ])
async def _ban(ctx, osoba: discord.Member, powód: str):
    await osoba.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'Zbanowano {osoba}! Powód: {reason}')
```

And error:

```
  File "main.py", line 39
    create_option(
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error you got is beacsue you forgot to put a , between the two options

```py
@slash.slash(name="ban", description="Zbanuj osobę", guild_ids=guild_ids, options=[
                create_option(
                  name="osoba",
                  description="Osoba do zbanowania",
                  option_type=6,
                  required=True
                ),
                create_option(
                  name="powód",
                  description="Powód bana",
                  option_type=3,
                  required=True
                )
             ])
async def _ban(ctx, osoba: discord.Member, powód: str):
    await osoba.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'Zbanowano {osoba}! Powód: {reason}')
```